# no sound coming from external speakers, that are plugged into jack on my macbook pro

Tags: audio, headphones

haven't touched any settings, or downloaded any new software. I just started up my computer and the headphones jack that power my external speakers aren't working?! I get no sound at all. Yet, when I unplug it from the jack, the sound from the computer comes on (3 sec) later. I've been reading the different posts and trying to follow the steps that are given, but it's not working.

Comment: Can we assume you tested the speakers with another source?

Comment: nope. The speakers I have are Harman/Kardon, and I live alone. Why would they just randomly stop working? they were working fine yesterday. It has something to do with this damn macbook pro.

Comment: You might plug them into an iPhone or iPod just to be sure it's not the cable. It's a lot faster to just check than wonder why - for after all, the nature of something breaking is that it worked a moment ago and now it doesn't work anymore. No reasons are really needed...

Answer (score 1):

You can try setting the sound output manually from system preferences. Does you external speaker get listed here upon plugging in?

[image]

Comment: checked that already. That wasn't it. Again...somehow the computer (without anyone touching it) stopped producing sound. However 3 seconds after unplugging my external speakers, the computer sound comes back on. Plug it back in, and 3 sec later the sound goes away again.